# Change d-flex in a second row of container - React Js

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, containers, row, bootstrap-5

I'm new in React JS, i'm doing a personal proyect with React JS, bootstrap and Firebase.
I have a component ItemList that are creating the container and inside the container have a div that is creating a row.

In the row i have a data.map:

```
const ItemList = ({ data = []}) => {    
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row d-flex text-center justify-content-center">
                {data.map(i => <Item key={i.id} category={i.category} detail={i.detail} id={i.id}                      
                  img={i.img} name={i.name} price={i.price} stock={i.stock}  />)}
            </div>
        </div>
        <p className='mt-5'></p>
        </>
    );
}
```

the items are OK, the problem is how are appearing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCJON.png)

I need that independent of the items in the row (preferably 4) the second row start with the item in the left and not in the center.

I trying different metods inside the Container with d-flex and changinf the dflex in the row but is not working.

I think in don't use the container and use the grid system without bootstrap but i don't knwo if exist other solution.

When i use the normal left align i have a blank space in the right side that don't allow the center sight.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzSK1.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so. As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need that independent of the items in the row (preferably 4)

Use [Bootstrap's Row column](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#row-columns) class:  `row-cols-4`. [Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#row-columns) for more info. Each of your product cards needs a parent column  `<div class="col">..</div>` for it to work.

You're centering all your flex items using the class `justify-content-center`. You can [read about in the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content). Remove it to use default Flex `justify-content: start;`.